# How can I persist my pfx file inside a docker

Tags: docker, desktop-application, pfx

In my desktop application I have a pfx file that should be protected safely. If I am using docker for this application, how can I protect the pfx file inside the docker. It should not be accessible by the other applications and it should persist throughout the lifetime of the application.

Comment: Are you trying to run a Desktop app from inside of docker?  This isn't really how docker works as its primarily for headless services or web apps.

Comment: Ok.Thanks @newky2k. Currently I am storing the pfx file inside the filesystem. Is there any option to protect the pfx file using dockers.

Comment: Anyone who can run any `docker` command at all can trivially read or write any file on the host system or in any container.  By using Docker here you lose the protection you'd get from ordinary filesystem permissions (in effect by requiring the user to run your application as root).

Answer (score 0):

You could mount your pfx file as read only in your container.

By instance, if your file is in your current directory :

- With docker-compose

  ```yaml
  services:
    app:
      volumes:
        - ${PWD}/my_file.pfx:/path/in/container:ro
  ```
- With docker run:

  ```sh
  docker run -v ./my_file.pfx:/path/in/container:ro myimage
  ```